# How to parse json data which has different structure

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on my App, but got an error.  How can I parse a JSON payload which has different structure?

I suspected that the following line need to change: `final Map<String, dynamic> payloadData = jsonDecode(response.body);`

```
final Map<String, dynamic> payloadData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    
            if (payloadData['current'].length > 0) {
        
              for (final item in payloadData['current']) {
               //more code ...
          }
        }
```

When I run my code I got the following error `flutter: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'`

Here's my payload from API.

```
"current": [
        [
            "3",
            "22",
            "100",
            "Fri, 10 Nov 2023 03:00:00 +1300"
        ],
        [
            "1",
            "25",
            "94",
            "Fri, 10 Nov 2023 01:00:00 +1300"
        ]
    ],
    "region": {
        "a": {
            "low": [
                "11:54 am"
            ],
            "high": [
                "5:57 am"
            ]
        },
        "b": {
            "low": [
                "11:23 am"
            ],
            "high": [
                "5:27 am"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there seems to be an array around your result, check if the result json looks like this

```json
[{ "current": ....
```

if it's always an array, just change the signature and drilldown

```dart
final List<dynamic> payloadArray = jsonDecode(response.body);

final Map<String, dynamic> payloadData = payloadArray[0];
    
            if (listData['current'].length > 0) {
        
              for (final item in listData['current']) {
               //more code ...
          }
        }
```